# Storyboard crash - coding-compliant key sceneViewController

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, key

I'm getting an intermittent crash using Storyboards in iOS 5. Every so often, I get a SIGABRT when I try to instantiate a new object with a view controller from my Storyboard. It seems like a very generic error, but I can't find anyone else that's seen this. Thanks for your help!

```
SectionLandscapeViewController *sectionViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SectionLandscapeViewController"];
```

And the crash...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIProxyObject 0xa0fba20> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key sceneViewController.'
```

Comment: same issue for me.. did you fix it yet?

Comment: I'm also interested in aswer to this question

Comment: I get this running on my iphone 4 but not in the simulator. Very strange, very irritating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9498693/1861181 solved it for me, if you are using a separate xib for storyboard viewController. Just make sure to put it in loadView, not viewDidLoad...

Answer (score 4):

Try to use storyboard ID that different from real UIViewController class name.

Comment: Thank you, Fitsyu. In my case your solution helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Open your .xib file for this controller and right click on "File Owner" and check if you have connected any wrong property or outlets. You will find a small yellow icon on the right side of outlet if it is a wrong one. Just remove that and try.

Comment: Thanks, but it's a Storyboard. The view controller's outlets and properties all look fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by doing a "Reset Content and Settings" in the IPhone Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Running it in simulator:**

Try `Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings`

**On Device**

Try deleting and reinstalling the app