# Simple graph draw task for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, quartz-graphics

I need to draw a simple graph, but I have no experience with custom draw iPhone graphics yet, so I hope, somebody can help me.

Task is simple: I need to draw graph background from .png file from resource, and draw points, also from bundled .png-files on some positions on background.

For drawing, I created descendant from UIView, and use following lines of code:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 500);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, [[UIImage imageNamed:@"graph.png"] CGImage]);
```

But its not working.

The first problem, I can't solve - UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext returns nil.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you putting this code in `- drawRect:`?

Comment: did you add the above code in the drawrect of your UIVIew?

Comment: Yes, this code in - drawRect:

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problems with this code.

```
- (void) drawGrid{
    UIImage *sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sungraph.png"];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height), NO, 0);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceImage.size.width, sourceImage.size.height);
    self.frame = rectangle;

    [sourceImage drawInRect:rectangle];
}

- (void) finalizeImage{
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:newImage];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height);
    [self addSubview:imgView];    
}
```

From **initWithFrame** of my class I call first function.
After, I add some data to graph (draw lines, etc)
And call **finalizeImage** at the end.

Comment: You are adding a subView that is the same that I said if you use the interface builder. Don't know if that was the only problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to add your View in your xib/storyboard.

In your story board open the utilities menu and add a View to the screen you are trying to draw into. Then change the class of the View to your class that extends View.

You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view) in the section "Using the 5 Star Rating View" to add your View into storyboard.

For more information you can:

- Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard) on stackoverflow
- Check if you made all steps necessary for your costum View in the tutorial or following this [blog](http://www.hacheka.com/a-custom-view-in-ios/) (this blog doesn't have the storyboard part)