# Dragging views into the scene dock in interface builder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, outlet

I'm working on an existing project and I noticed there was a UIView in the scene dock in IB.

I then noticed you can actually drag any view into the dock, toolbars, buttons, switches etc

What's the purpose of this, I couldn't find anything searching google but it looks useful?

In my case it seems to link 'selectedBackgroundView' to each of the cells.

[image: Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

When i was searching for creating custom view using storyboard i found that some are using it for custom views. See this [Custom views with Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard/14515818#14515818)

Comment: Wow, thats pretty cool although doesn't feel like that's what Apple intended it to be used for. In this project, if you control drag from a cell to the UIView in the dock, you get these options to link it to...http://postimg.org/image/ssrpop1oj/

Comment: Just had a go at the tableView trick, doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can drag any object to the scene. And then it is showed in that gray dock. For example Search Bar Controllers or any other object you want to be automatically created and linked when the view is "loaded from nib".