# Load custom UITableViewCell from Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, heightforrowatindexpath

Currently I'm using auto layout with storyboard to dynamically resize custom `UITableViewCell`'s. Everything is working as it should except there is memory leak when scrolling.

I know the problem is from calling

```
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

from inside

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My question is this, what would be the best way to create a reference cell? How to load a cell from storyboard without `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?

And is it ok to maybe call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` from `viewDidLoad` and create a reference cell as a property?

I need reference cell for sizing purposes.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding how to create reference cell (see original question), there are couple of options as I can see:

1. create a custom cell with XIB, great article here -> [a link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/06/07/prototype-table-cells-and-storyboards.html)!

   - this was pointed out to me by @smileyborg, thanks!
2. create your custom cell in code, along with constraints.
3. create your custom cell in storyboard as prototype cell

   - after that there are 2 options:

     - drag and drop custom cell from table view to the storyboard scene, as a top level nib object (not part of the view hierarchy), and simply create outlet to it.
     - copy custom cell and paste it to the storyboard scene. When using it this way, there is no need to register original cell with table for dequeue.
     - minor problem with both approaches is that once you drag and drop custom cell to the storyboard scene, you will not be able to see it visually and arrange UI.
   - great article here -> [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard)!

Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 1):

> And is it ok to maybe call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier from viewDidLoad and create a reference cell as a property?

Yes, you can do this. Or lazy initialize the property:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)referenceCell
{
    if (!_referenceCell) {
        _referenceCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    return _referenceCell;
}
```

Comment: It seems that this also will create leaks. I'm testing it right now.

Comment: Last night, I had an conversation with Tyler Fox (@smileyborg), he has created a great example for auto layout and dynamic table view height [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#18746930), and he also confirmed that using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath will probably create leaks.

Comment: Curious why @smileyborg thinks this will leak. My [TLIndexPathTools](https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools) uses this method to automatically calculate cell height nobody has ever reported a leak. And I just tested it. If you've got a scenario where it leaks, I'd like to take a look.

Comment: @TimothyMoose It's true that cells will leak when dequeued and not returned in cellForRowAtIndexPath. See discussion of this here: https://github.com/caoimghgin/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout/issues/16 Note that this probably isn't an issue if you're only calling it once and then storing the one cell for later use. But if you did this a number of times (or perhaps your view controller is created & destroyed frequently), you will see each of these cells hangs around with a retain count of 1 and thus is never deallocated.

Comment: @smileyborg Yep, I'm only dequeuing one per cell ID and reusing it. I keep them in a dictionary and they get dequeued properly along with the view controller. Since this is being done outside of the regular cell reuse cycle, I wouldn't expect them to be discarded from the reuse pool. Thanks for clarifying what you meant.

Comment: @smileyborg had a conversation with an apple engineer, he said that "That same method returns an autoreleased object, and in principle should not cause a memory leak."

Comment: @smileyborg but of course I agree with you about the leak, and it's very noticeable on my end because of frequent alloc/dealloc. It's probably a bug on their end.

Answer (score 0):

You can just dequeue the cell once and store the height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSNumber *height;

    if (!height) 
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCustomCell"];
        height = @(cell.bounds.size.height);
    }

    return [height floatValue];
}
```