# How to create popup in storyboard - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, popup, storyboard

I am creating iPhone application by using storyboard. In this, how to create a popup on storyboard and how to add and dismiss this popup on viewcontroller.

Popup Sample Image:

[image]

i want to add popup in storyboard like this:

[image]

Comment: do you want to show alertview ?@Hari Babu

Comment: @sanjeet no, now i added sample image like that i need.

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mtpopupwindow

Comment: This is a great tutorial for this answer. It teaches you everything you will need to know: http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/

Answer (score 0):

You might create it like this (don't forget to add `<UIPopoverControllerDelegate>` to presenting view controller class)

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @"MainStoryboard" bundle : nil];
    MyCustomPopoverContentVC* customContentViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier : @"MyCustomPopoverContentVC"];

// initialize popover controller with content view controller
UIPopoverController* popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: anyCustomViewController];
popoverController.delegate = self;
// change popoverContentSize here
CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0, 500.0, 500.0);
popoverController.popoverContentSize = contentFrame.size;
// present popover controller
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect: _buttonRectForPopoverController inView: self.view permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated: YES];
```

and somewhere else in your presenting view controller class an example `UIPopoverControllerDelegate' method:

```
// refreshes the rect from where the popover is shown after interface orientations.
// this method is necessary and recommended by apple's documentation
- (void) popoverController : (UIPopoverController*) popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect : (inout CGRect*) rect inView : (inout UIView*__autoreleasing*) view
{
    *rect = _buttonRectForPopoverController;
}
```