# swift - adding constraints to a modal view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, layout, constraints

On my storyboard I have 2 viewControllers, one with a background image and one with blur effect an a label

[image: storyboard]

I would like to present the second view on top of the first one. I'm using the following code:

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as secondViewController
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

I'm using `addSubView` and not `presentViewController`, because the latest cause my first view to disappear after the transition completed, and all i got was a black screen.

as long as I don't add constraints to the second view, my code seems to be at the right direction (see below):

[image]

However, the moment I'm adding constraints to the second view, it will not show at all.

**Q**:What is the correct way of displaying a second view controller as an overlay and give it the right constraints

**EDIT:** I've tried to add `vc.view.frame = self.view.frame` as suggested by @topher91. The view appears for an instants then disappears. Here is the debug view hierarchy: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be creating the overlay as a different view rather than as a new view controller. 
Then in the storyboard you can set the constraints relative to the parent view controller:

[Custom views with Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498010/custom-views-with-storyboard)

Alternatively, you can continue as you have done but before you addSubview set the frame of the overlay to be the same as the parent.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("second") as secondViewController

    vc.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check it out. Do you know if that is the right approach of creating modal overlays that encapsulate some logic?

Answer (score 0):

At the end it was all a constraints issue. My code for adding the view was really simple:

```
var registrationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registration") as RegistrationViewController
    self.view.addSubview(registrationVC.view)
```

and here are the constraints for the blur view:

```
<constraints>
    <constraint firstItem="iT5-uU-X9N" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="V3l-eN-oQT" secondAttribute="leading" id="7EH-Cu-ZOY"/>
    <constraint firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="iT5-uU-X9N" secondAttribute="centerY" id="AZj-sB-ByG"/>
    <constraint firstItem="fEQ-lT-dLv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iT5-uU-X9N" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KF2-8m-P2T"/>
    <constraint firstItem="iT5-uU-X9N" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="V3l-eN-oQT" secondAttribute="top" id="PsG-ox-lQL"/>
    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iT5-uU-X9N" secondAttribute="trailing" id="cYs-qE-sVQ"/>
    <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="iT5-uU-X9N" secondAttribute="centerX" id="qEL-Ln-Is9"/>
 </constraints>
```